# Reorder the rows of data frame in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I reorder the data frame? Where I would like the bottom row to be on the top and the top will be on the bottom (reverse).

Comment: and the middle rows would be as it is?

Comment: yeah. the second to the last will be on the 2nd top and the 2nd top will be second to the last

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to reverse the dataframe, there are multiple ways to do this.

One way in base R would be using `rev`

```
df[rev(1:nrow(df)), ]

#    a  b
#10 10 20
#9   9 19
#8   8 18
#7   7 17
#6   6 16
#5   5 15
#4   4 14
#3   3 13
#2   2 12
#1   1 11
```

---

If interested in `dplyr` solution we could do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% slice(n() - row_number() + 1)
```

**data**

```
 df <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
```

Answer (score 3):

An easier option is to just do `nrow(df):1` as the row index

```
df[nrow(df):1, ]
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[.N:1]
```

---

Or an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(row_number()))
```